# Is scope=request good fit for high-load spring application?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, scope, named-scope

Is it common practice when singleton beans was injected to request-scoped beans, which injected to singleton-scoped beans?
For example, something like this:

```
@Scope(value="request", proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)
public class CurrentUser {
    @Resource
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    ...
}

public class ApplicationController {

    @Autowired
    private CurrentUser currentUser;
    ...
}
```

Is any overhead expenses for memory management possible? This implementation is tread-safe?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially what is going to happen is that there will be an instance of `CurrentUser` for every active http request. The instances are managed behind a proxy created by Spring and the instance itself is maintained as a http request attribute and the lifecycle is tied to this request.

I would say that this is going to be costly in terms of the effort to instantiate and autowire each `CurrentUser` request instance. It should not be costly memory wise as the instances are short lived and scoped to request. On whether the instance is thread safe, yes it is.

One bug though, the proxyMode has to be `ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS` as your `CurrentUser` class does not implement any interfaces.

Comment: Thanks! About proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES - I know this point, thanks. I shortened inheritance details.